# Simple JavaScript image slide without preload array

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm fairly new to the JS . i have created a html page and want to include a image slider. it has to be automatic. i did some coding, and when i check the console, its running but the image is changing.
and when i get this element with "getElementById()" it says "sld" is null,(line7), ie " sld.src = eval("img"+step+".src") " is null, they are saying. Where am i doing it wrong.

***JS - HTML***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var img1 = new Image();
        img1.src="slide_show/1.jpg";
        var img2 = new Image();
        img1.src="slide_show/2.jpg";
        var img3 = new Image();
        img1.src="slide_show/3.jpg";
        var img4 = new Image();
        img1.src="slide_show/4.jpg";

    </script>
```

***JS***

```
var step = 2;
function slideit()
{
    console.log("i'm called");
    console.log(step);
    var sld = document.getElementsByName("sli");
    sld.src = eval("img" + step + ".src");
    if (step < 3) {
        console.log("for loop");
        step++;
    }
    else{
        step = 1;
    }
    console.log("timeout");
    setTimeout("slideit()", 250);
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="main_section">
 <img name="sli" src="slideShow/1.1.jpg" id="slide_show"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple corrections required in your code

- No need to create image array and you can simply store the values in plain string array.
- No need to use document.getElementsByName, but you can instead use document.getElementById. Pass the ID of the image tag.
- Note also you need to change the setTimeout call.

The corrected code will look like following

```
var img = ["slide_show/1.jpg", "slide_show/2.jpg", "slide_show/3.jpg", "slide_show/4.jpg"];
```

Change your JS to

```
var step = 2;
function slideit()
{
    console.log("i'm called");
    console.log(step);
    var sld = document.getElementsById("sli");
    sld.src = img[step];
    if (step < 3) {
        console.log("for loop");
        step++;
    }
    else{
        step = 1;
    }
    console.log("timeout");
    setTimeout(slideit, 250);
}
```

Comment: well, i want to know why the eval() function didnt work? using the array is good, but can you fix it the way i intended, one variable for each image, and using eval() function. and i did used "getElementById("slide_show") " but error occurs, saying "sld" is null

Comment: Hi River, You said that you don't want to use preload functionality. Using Image object you are exactly doing the opposite. The eval should work in your case, but the assignment to sld variable will result in array and not scalar variable. If you are getting it as a null, then you need to check when your script is getting fired? Is it before the DOM tree is initialized or after. It will be better to call the slideit function after DOM tree is ready. Hint: Use document.onreadystatechange https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState

Comment: TypeError: sld is null

Comment: i tried assigning a image from root to 'sld', still its wont change the image.

Comment: @RiverCRPhoenix, why don't you assign id to the img tag as `id="sli"` and then make use of `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsByName`. This should surely work. Also turn on request trapping plugin, it will indicate whether the server side request is being sent while sld.src is being executed. Additionally turn on error reporting the browser.